# Where is the segmentation fault in the server/client side?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, serversocket

***is complied successfully but doesn't run bcz of segmentation fault***

1. The data that the client sends is a string provided as the second client command­line argument. The basic Echo client prints the single string of data sent back by the Echo server.The form of the command line and print line for the basic Echo server are:
   **Compilation:
   Server> gcc  _EchoServer.c ­o _EchoServer
   Output command: Server> ./_EchoServer
   Server started ... waiting for connection ...**

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int servsocket,nBytes,i;
    char buf[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr,clientAddr;
    servsocket=socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    socklen_t addrsize, clientsize;

    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    bind(servsocket,(struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    
    addrsize=sizeof(clientAddr);
    nBytes = recvfrom(servsocket,buf,1024,0,(struct sockaddr *)&clientAddr, &addrsize);
    printf("%s",buf);
    sendto(servsocket,buf,strlen(buf)+1,0,(struct sockaddr *)&clientAddr,addrsize);     
    close(servsocket);
    return 0;
}
```

**Compilation:
Client> gcc  _EchoClient.c ­o _EchoClient
Output command: Client> ./_EchoClient 172.31.132.x “echo this string!!”
Received from server: echo this string!!
172.31.132.x**

```c
//client side
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<netdb.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    
    int clsocket,nBytes;
    char buf[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    socklen_t addr_size;
        
    clsocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr =  inet_addr(argv[2]);
    
    int addrsize=sizeof(serverAddr);
    nBytes = strlen(argv[3]) + 1;
    sendto(clsocket,argv[3],nBytes,0,(struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr,addrsize);
    recvfrom(clsocket,buf,1024,0,(struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, &addrsize);
    printf("From server %s\n",buf);
    close(clsocket);

}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Anik Sarker Akash - Your example output doesn't exhibit the segmentation fault. You have to provide an example which does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
serverAddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr =  inet_addr(argv[2]);
```

If you check the arguments passed in the client, argv[1] = 172.31.132.x and argv[2] = "echo the string!!"; none of which specify the port and the ip as mentioned in the two lines above from the Echo Client code.

Instead enter -

```
serverAddr.sin_port = htons(8080); //taking a simple example of http server
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr =  inet_addr(argv[1]); //since argument 1 contains the IP address and not the second argument
```